# Android phone display stuck and restart not working

Tags: usb, adb

My Android phone's display is stuck and none of the three buttons volume up/down and lock are working. I tried calling myself from the Android device manager, which didn't work.

I connected the phone to my laptop, it shows up connected as an MTP device.
But, when it try `adb devices`, it doesn't show up.

What can I do to regain control of my phone?

For now I am just waiting until the battery is empty, so that I can restart it by plugging into a power source. Is there a better way?

Comment: Press and hold Volume Down button and Power buttons together for a 10 seconds and your mobile phone should restart.

Comment: oh wow, that worked. I has tried that but not long enough I guess. I had tried all the possible combinations of those buttons for at least 5-6 seconds. Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in the comments by @Sandeep , but I hate unanswered questions, so:

**Try a Hard Reset:** Hard Reset essentially forces your phone (or any device, for that matter) to reset regardless of what it was doing or where it was stuck. It's the first thing you should try if all else has failed and you need your device to work.

Hard Resets, at least consumer devices with limited buttons, is usually done by holding the power off button for longer with another key.
**For Android, it's usually the power button along with the Volume/Up Down Button for about 10 seconds or more.** For iPhones, it's usually the Home Button and the Power button. For PC/MACs, just holding the power button for a long time can cause a force shut down.

Comment: well i was trying to do that only, just that I was not doing it for 10s long